# AppceleratorStudio : Paused ipad App cannot resume back if ever called Ti.Media.hideCamera() for iOS 9 and above

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I am writing an app that can capture image and display.
For **iOS 9 and above**, will issue this after call the showCamera function as below. if pause the app, it will never resume back to the screen i paused.

My app is using : 
**Titanium SDK - 3.4.1 , 
Xcode - 6.4 ,
Node.js - 0.12.7**

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success : function(event) {     
        if (callback)
            callback({pic: event.media});
        Ti.Media.hideCamera();
        $.winCameraView.close();
    },
    cancel : function() {
    },
    error : function(error) {
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title : 'Camera'
        });
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
            a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
        } else {
            a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }
        a.show();
    },
    saveToPhotoGallery: false,
    overlay : overlay,
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().scale(scale),
    showControls : false,
    mediaTypes : Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO,
    autohide : false
});
```

really frustrated, Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pausing' the app? Pressing the home button of the device?

Comment: Yes @GerbenHofman , either home button pressing or sleep button or switching apps, when it resume it will go to the mainPage of the app. The previous page where I pause will not trigger back.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on an iPhone 7 with iOS 9.3(Ti 5.4.0 SDK) and it worked within my app. I pressed the home button whilst the camera was open, started a different app and went back into my app and my camera got booted just like I left the app. The difference between you and me, apart from the different SDK, is that I don't use an overlay, which might cause the problem.

My media settings are:

```
showControls:       true,
animated:           false,
saveToPhotoGallery: true,
// allowEditing and mediaTypes are iOS-only settings
allowEditing:       false,
mediaType:          [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
```

I suggest you to use my settings and try again, let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Try with your option. The issue is still happening at my end. After take the picture and called “Ti.Media.hideCamera()”, press home button -> go back to the app -> and the app will be in fresh start. 
I suppose Titanium might have fixed this issue in a newer SDK (perhaps) but my environment does not allow to update to newest version. Any ways I can do this the other way round or is there a point or note in the Titanium version log that support my issue?